# how to show alert in lock screen? Is there any private api to these?

Tags: ios, push-notification, lockscreen, iphone-privateapi

In one of my project i want to show alert in lock screen. currently it shows banner as push notification but i show this feature in one of app. does they use private api to do this? if there is api to do these ,does any one know?

[image]

Comment: It is hard to see because the image is too blurred, but it looks like they have attached actions to the notification

Comment: @ Paulw11..when in these app the phone is unlocked and push notification comes it shows alert and same thing same type of alert is displayed when app is locked..&  i don't know how to attach action in notification do u have any idea what to do to attach action in notification?